# Q: AngularJS, How can I put images into my background div?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to put some images into my background div. 
I expected those 5 image files will be in the div with ".well" class, but they just were spread out of that div. So, here's my question.
How can I put those image files stably into **.well** div?
There's my code and result below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
 <head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <script>
   angular.module("exampleApp", [])
   .controller("exampleCtrl", function($scope){
 
   $scope.data = [
    { movie:"Pandora", date:"2016-12-07", img:"pandora.gif"   },
    { movie:"Lalaland", date:"2016-12-07", img:"lalaland.gif" },
    { movie:"Willyoubethere", date:"2016-12-14", img:"willYouBeThere.gif" },
    { movie:"brother", date:"2016-11-23", img:"brother.gif" },
    { movie:"Animal", date:"2016-11-16", img:"fantasticAnimalDictionary.gif" }
   ];
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="well">
    <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="data in data">
     <img ng-src={{data.img}} />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[The result from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20ZJ5.png)

Comment: can we see "well" class css?

Comment: we can help if u proved the css of well class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `row` class with `well`. like this

```
<div class="well row">
   <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="data in data">
       <img ng-src={{data.img}} />
   </div>
</div>
```

`row` class are containers of columns.The row provides the columns a place to live, ideally having columns that add up to 12. It also acts as a wrapper since all the columns float left, additional rows don’t have overlaps when floats get weird.

Comment: Awesome. It works really well. What does 'row' function do in this situation?